# Restrict type in concrete instantiation of a generic

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is it possible to restrict the type to a subset of a class hierarchy during a concrete instantiation of a generic class.

For example if I have an abstract factory class when I create a concrete factory can I limit the types that are placed into the factory to a limited set of types.

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory<K,V>

public sealed class CornerProcessorFactory : AbstractFactory<XYZ, Type>
```

When I declare the CornerProcessorFactory I would like to limit the types passed to a particular base class or interface in the hierarchy, but still have the value type passed as a type and not an instantiated class.

Comment: "passed to a particular base class or interface in the hierarchy" Can you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constrain your Type parameters by using the where keyword:

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory<TKey, TValue> : SomeOtherGenericClass<TKey>
   where TKey: class, new()
   where TValue: struct
```

so here, im saying that TKey has to be a reference type and contain a default constructor and TValue has to be a value type. You can also specify that it derives from a class or implements an interface. Something like:

```
   where TKey: IMyInterface
```

or

```
   where TKey: MyBaseClass
```

So in the first one, im basically demanding that whatever gets passed in as my T has to implement the IMyInterface. In the second one, im demanding that whatever gets passed in as T has to derive from MyBaseClass

Comment: public sealed class CornerProcessorFactory<T> : AbstractFactory<XYZ, T> where T : class    with an instantiation of    CornerProcessorFactory<CornerProcessor>.Instance.Register(-XYZ.BasisX, typeof(CornerProcessorMinusX)); results in compilation errors (removing the typeof does no better)

Comment: thats because XYZ isn't defined from CornerProcessorFactory<T>. The generic parent class needs someway to define itself. Either create the XYZ parameter in the derived class CornerProcessorFactory or hard code it. Remember that XYZ in this case is still of type T so it still needs to be defined somewhere. For instance, if you were to follow the naming convention, you'd actually end up with AbstractFactory<TTypeA, TTypeB>. Both have to be defined at some point

Answer (score 1):

Using something like:

```
public sealed class CornerProcessorFactory<T> : AbstractFactory<XYZ, T> where T: ISomething
```

If you want the restriction only for CornerProcessorFactory.

Comment: With this solution I need to instantiate a class, but I would like to pass the Type of the class not an instantiated instance of

Comment: That's actually what you're doing. The parameters between brackets are Types, not instances. See my answer below for a little more explanation.

Comment: @seewtfa, you don't need to instantiate. This is restriction on type not on instance. I Intentionally let you with one restricted parameter (T) and the other, non-restricted one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory<K,V>{}

public sealed class CornerProcessorFactory<K,V> : 
    AbstractFactory<K, V> 
    where K : IFoo 
    where V : struct{ }
```